# how to INPUT a variable(a letter) into calculator class function

Tags: java

here is the code 
 I have a calculator class , right now it only accounts for numbers but im trying to get it to account for a variable and set the value of the variable to a specific number ie `5`

sorry if i was unclear. when i run this calculator , and input 1+1 it gives me 2 as the answer. but  i want to be able to include a varibable for example 3*x^2 or 3*y^2. with the value of the variable being 5. right now this code is unable to do that.

```
public class Calculator {

    // Allowable mathematical operators
    static final String operators = "+-*/%()^!";

    private String strPostfix;
    private String strInfix;
    private char chrVariable;
    private int intError;

    /**
     * Default constructor. Sets all local values to default values
     */
    public Calculator() {
        setEquation("");
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new equation.
     * @param equation The new equation.
     * @remarks Note that this also resets all values stored same as creating a new object
     */
    public void setEquation(String equation)
    {
        // Remove any spaces, as they aren't necessary 
        strInfix = equation.replace(" ", "").trim();
        strPostfix = "";
        chrVariable = '\0';
        intError = -2;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the character location of the error found. -1 means no error found.
     * @return An integer specifying the location of the error. 
     */
    public int get_ErrorLocation()
    {
        return intError + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the operators being used 
     * @return The operators
     */
    public String get_Operators()
    {
        return operators;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the post fix equation stored in memory for this object
     * @return A post fix equation stored in a string
     */
    public String get_PostFix()
    {
        return strPostfix;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the variable that is in the equation. '~' means no variable found.
     * @return The variable being used in the equation. 
     */
    public char get_Variable()
    {
        return chrVariable;
    }

    /**
     * Solves the equation stored in memory for this instance, and stores it in memory
     * @return A solution to a pre-existing equation
     * @throws NoEquationException Occurs when attempting to solve an equation that doesn't exist
     * @throws DivisionByZeroException Thrown when attempting to divide by zero
     * @throws InvalidEquationException Occurs if an equation is invalid for an undefined reason
     * @throws ExistingVariableException Occurs when attempting to use two variables
     * @throws InvalidCharacterException Occurs when an invalid character is entered
     */
    public double Solve() throws NoEquationException, DivisionByZeroException, InvalidEquationException, InvalidCharacterException, ExistingVariableException
    {
        strPostfix = PostFix().trim();
        System.out.println(strPostfix);

        return SolvePost();
    }

    /**
     * Determines the precendence of a give mathematical operator
     * @param value The mathematical operator
     * @return The precendence of the operator
     */
    private short precedence(char value) {
        switch (value) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;
        case '!':
            return 3;
        case '^':
            return 4;
        default:
            return -1; 
        }
    }


    /**
     * Turns an infix equation into post-fix
     * @return The post-fix equivalent of the equation
     * @throws InvalidEquationException When an invalid equation is given
     * @throws ExistingVariableException Occurs when attempting to use two variables
     * @throws InvalidCharacterException Occurs when an invalid character is entered
     * @throws NoEquationException Occurs when attempting to solve an equation that doesn't exist
     */
    private String PostFix() throws InvalidEquationException, InvalidCharacterException, ExistingVariableException {
        // Backup the equation
        String infix = strInfix;

        String postfix = "";
        char current;
        char chrVariable;
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        boolean hasDec = false;

        // For every character in the string



        for ( int idx = 0; idx < infix.length(); ++idx ) {
            current = infix.charAt(idx);







            // If it is a digit or letter , just add it to postfix
            if ( Character.isDigit(current) ) {
                postfix += current;





            // If it is a decimal, make sure there is only one per number

            }else if (Character.isLetter(current))
                postfix+=current;

            else if( current == '.' ) {
                if (!hasDec) 
                    postfix += String.valueOf(current);

                else 
                    throw new InvalidEquationException();

                hasDec = true;



            // Otherwise, its an operator
            } 
            else {
                postfix += " ";
                hasDec = false;
                char peek;
                // If there's an opening brace, just push it to the stack
                if ( current == '(' )
                    stack.push(current);
                // If its a closing brace, find pop until you find the opening one
                else if ( current == ')' ) {
                    while ( !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(' ) {
                        postfix += stack.pop() + " ";
                    }
                    // If the stack is empty, '(' was not found, error
                    if (stack.isEmpty()) { throw new InvalidEquationException('('); }
                    // Remove the '(' from the list
                    stack.pop();
                } else {
                    if ( current == '-' && ( idx == 0 || operators.contains(String.valueOf(infix.charAt(idx - 1)))))  {
                                postfix += current;
                    } else {
                        short prec = precedence(current);
                        if ( prec == -1 ) {
                            intError = idx;
                            throw new InvalidCharacterException();
                        }
                        // Pop off everything that has greater or equal precedence 
                        if ( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
                            peek = stack.peek();
                            while ( precedence(current) <= precedence(peek) ) {
                                postfix += stack.pop() + " ";
                                if ( !stack.isEmpty() ) 
                                    peek = stack.peek();
                                else
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        // Now add the current onto the stack
                        stack.push(current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Finally, empty out the stack
        while ( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
            postfix += " " + stack.pop();
        }

        postfix = postfix.trim();
        while ( postfix.contains("  ") ) {
            postfix = postfix.replaceAll("  ", " ");
        }

        return postfix;
        }




    /**
     * Solves the post-fix equation
     * @return The solution to the equation
     * @throws NoEquationException Thrown when PostFix equation not set
     * @throws DivisionByZeroException Thrown when attempting to divide by zero
     * @throws InvalidEquationException When an invalid equation is given
     */
    private double SolvePost() throws NoEquationException, DivisionByZeroException, InvalidEquationException {
        // Make sure there is an equation to solve


        if ( strPostfix.trim().isEmpty() )
            throw new NoEquationException();

        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
        String tokens[] = strPostfix.split(" "); 

        for ( String current : tokens ) {
            try {
                // If its a number, just push it
                stack.push(Double.parseDouble(current));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If its not an operator, there's a problem
                if ( current.length() > 1 || !operators.contains(current) )

                    throw new InvalidEquationException();

                // there must be two operands, otherwise there's a problem
                double first = 0, second = 0;
                try {
                    second = stack.pop();
                    if ( current.charAt(0) != '!' )
                        first = stack.pop();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new InvalidEquationException();
                }

                // Do the appropriate math
                switch ( current.charAt(0) ) {
                case '+':
                    stack.push(first + second);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    stack.push(first - second);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    stack.push(first * second);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    // Make sure its not division by zero
                    if (second == 0) { throw new DivisionByZeroException(); }
                    stack.push(first / second);
                    break;
                case '%':
                    stack.push(first % second);
                    break;
                case '^':
                    stack.push(Math.pow(first, second));
                    break;
                case '!':
                    if ( (int)second != second || second < 0 )
                        throw new InvalidEquationException();
                    int result = 1;
                    for ( int i = 2; i <= second; ++i )
                        result *= i;
                    stack.push((double)result);
                    break;
                default:
                    // Anything else isn't valid
                    throw new InvalidEquationException(); 
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you give us more details about your problem?

Comment: Need more details to better understand your problem.... this is insufficient..

Comment: You want to introduce variables and assignment?

Comment: Funny but the code is much clearer than you... It turns infix equation into postfix and then calculates it. It keeps operators priority and support operations as factorial and power as well. All that said - it's not clear what do you mean by "get it to account for a variable". If you want to original equation string to contain a variable `x` and set it to `5` - simply use `replaceAll('x', '5')` on the original string.

Comment: sorry if i was unclear. when i run this calculator , and input 1+1 it gives me 2 as the answer. but  i want to be able to include a varibable for example 3*x^2 or 3*y^2. with the value of the variable being 5. right now this code is unable to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i set a value to a variable ie x in a calulator class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349069/how-do-i-set-a-value-to-a-variable-ie-x-in-a-calulator-class)